# Unable to switch TTYs in RHEL8

Tags: linux, console, kernel, rhel, tty

I am using MobaXtern to connect to `RHEL8 VM` unable to switch to ttys by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> .. <kbd>F6</kbd> keys.
I have also tried `chvt 1` command but it is not working too.

```
[root@localhost log]# chvt 4
[root@localhost log]# tty
/dev/pts/1
```

Comment: isn't it a moba setup for accepting ctrl alt f1 to f(n)  on µ$oft windows ?  as a second question chvt is not really used that way usually ; chvt 4  runs commands that prompts results to that 2> 3> etc... to that vt  not current shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve it by adding `Shift key` before the `Ctrl Key` as below

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> .. <kbd>F6</kbd>